# How to check if credentials are correct or database does exists before creating "new PDO"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$dbname='database_name';

$dbuser='database_user';
$dbpass='database_password';
$dbhost='localhost';
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

How can I check if database_name, database_user, database_password are correct or if the database exists.

Comment: `try { /* Try to connect */ } catch (PDOException $ex) { .. }`

Comment: The only way to really check is to try to use them, just like that. Use try/catch and check for errors to make sure the connection works.

Comment: try/catch/if/while/if/die; and *Don't pass GO* - Pay $200.

Answer (score 2):

As it has been suggested, use a try/catch:

```
$dbname='database_name';
$dbuser='database_user';
$dbpass='database_password';
$dbhost='localhost';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // if you do not want to output message you can log the errors
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $errorCode = $e->getCode();
}
```